# Tesseract only works when Application Pool Identity in IIS is set to Local System

Tags: c#, iis, tesseract, applicationpoolidentity

I have an ASP.NET Web Application which uses Tesseract OCR 4.1.1

When the project is deployed in IIS, the system works perfectly when the application pool identity is set to Local System. However when the applicatioon pool identity is set the Local Service, Network Service or ApplicationPoolIdentity, system throws the following error :

Failed to initialise tesseract engine. See https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-1 for details.

When I search the error message, it is written that error message is due to failure of reading tesseract train data. Why do we need "Local System" authority for only reading the traindata? I just wasn't convinced why I must select Local System in order to use Tessearct OCR engine. Could you explain me or suggest a document for this issue? And how can I solve the issue with fewer privileges than a Local System account.

Comment: Local System: Trusted account that has high privileges and also has access to network resources. I think the reason for this situation is that the train data needs higher permissions to access.

Comment: This may be related to where the train data is stored.